# Why do Java arrays act like this?

Tags: java, arrays

I am quite new to java and don't understand quite how this works.

```
int[] x = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int[] y = x;
y[2] = 10;
```

In the code why is it that `x[2]` is now equal to 10 as well as `y[2]` being equal to 10?

I don't understand why it doesn't only set `y[2] = 10` and leave `x[2] = 6`.

Is this because the y array is a reference to the x array?

Comment: bcoz `x` and `y` are referencing the same array

Comment: since you  x and y have same array, when you want to change value of y, it also change value of x.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this because the y array is a reference to the x array?

Yes. The line `int[] y = x;` says exactly that.

If you want a copy, you can do

```
int[] y = Arrays.copyOf(x, x.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

in Java arrays are objects, even if the hold primitives... so when you do 
something like:

```
int[] x = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] y = x;
y[2] = 10;
System.out.println(x[2] + "  " + y[2]);
```

you are assigning x and y the same reference... any change in x will take effect in y and vice versa... both are "pointing" to the same object...

take a look to the image below for a more illustrative explanation

[image]